# How to invoke adobe's expressInstall from action script

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe

I have an existing Flash app. I want the user to interact with it. Then in order to get a better experience, I want to prompt the user to get the latest version (if she doesnt have).

I have looked at swfobject, and I can do a external interface call to showExpressInstall(). However, then I get into a situation of figuring out how to overlay that dialog over my application.

So,

1. Is there a way to trigger the prompt, from within flash ?
2. If done using swfobject, how to get over the overlay issue ?

Comment: I ended up hiding the flash and showing a screen shot in a div. Then overlay the express installer over it.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR can manage app updates by itself if you define some things. You can even make a custom update UI. Try these resources:

[Link 1](http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2008/04/custom_update_ui_for_applicati.html) 
[Link 2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/updating-air-apps-native-installer.html)